# How to toggle show/hide element in Fable?

Tags: html, f#, togglebutton, fable-f#

I want to have a trivial show/hide content behavior in Fable.
Something just like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp).

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>
```

What is the most adequate way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a much larger question than you realize, because underneath it is the question of "how should I best arrange my Fable application"? The approach you've taken in your answer is roughly parallel to using JQuery in a Javascript application: you write code that directly manipulates the DOM to achieve the result you want. If that's the architectural style you've chosen — and for really simple apps, it's a perfectly good choice — then your answer can't much be improved on. The only time the "manipulate the DOM directly" approach will run into problems is if your app grows to larger-than-trivial size. At that point, you'll want a better architecture. I'll get to recommending a better architecture in a moment, but first, let me recommend a small tweak to your code. Moving the `toggle` function outside of `toggleButton` would make it more versatile:

```
module Markup

open System
open Fable.Helpers.React
open Fable.Helpers.React.Props
open Fable.Import

let toggleBlockElem id _ = 
    let contentElement = Browser.document.getElementById id
    let display = if contentElement.style.display = "none" then "block" else "none"
    contentElement.style.display <- display

let toggleButton text content =
    let id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    div [] 
        [
            button [ OnClick (toggleBlockElem id) ] [ str text ]
            div [ Id id ] [ str content ]
        ]
```

That allows you to reuse this function in functions like `toggleLink` or `toggleCheckbox` if you find yourself needing those.

Now, I mentioned earlier that I would recommend a different architecture if your web app gets large. The architecture I recommend is [Elmish](https://elmish.github.io/elmish/). It's based on the architecture used in [Elm](https://elm-lang.org/); if you're not familiar with it, the basic idea is similar to React. It's a model/update/view architecture. The **model** is an immutable data structure. There's also a **message** type defined; in Elmish, this is probably an F# discriminated union. The **update** function takes a model and a message as its two parameters, and returns a new model. The **view** function takes a model and a "**dispatch**" function as its two parameters (the "dispatch" function will be supplied by Elmish, you don't have to write it) and returns an abstract tree of HTML-like elements. Elmish then passes those elements to something like React to do the actual DOM update. (React will, essentially, diff the "old" DOM tree and the "new" DOM tree, according to a process much like [the one described here](https://elm-lang.org/blog/blazing-fast-html) for Elm).

All that is a bit much to take in, so let's look at a simple example that just toggles the visibility of a `div`. **CAUTION:** I have not tested this, just typed it in to the Stack Overflow answer box. There may be bugs in the code below; it's intended as an illustrative example rather than a working example. (For a VERY thorough working example of Elmish in action, see https://mangelmaxime.github.io/fulma-demo/ — though note that that example has an advanced architecture incorporating multiple "layers" of parent-child hierarchy in the data model, and may be hard to wrap your mind around at first glance).

Let's start with defining your data model. Since this is a trivial example, the model is similarly trivial; so trivial, in fact, that I'm going to add some extra data to it so that it actually makes sense to use a record type instead of a single bool:

```
type Model = { Visible: bool;
               DataNotAppearingInThisFilm: int }
```

(A more advanced model might involve a `Map<string, bool>` type to keep track of the visible status of multiple `div`s).

The message type is also trivial, so to make it a little bit interesting we'll allow for "Show", "Hide" *and* "Toggle" messages:

```
type Msg =
    | Show
    | Hide
    | Toggle
```

(The more advanced version would be `Show of string`, etc., passing the ID of the div to show).

The `update` function is similarly easy:

```
let update msg model =
    match msg with
    | Show -> { model with Visible = true }
    | Hide -> { model with Visible = false }
    | Toggle -> { model with Visible = not model.Visible }
```

Finally, the `view` function would look like this:

```
let view model dispatch =
    div [] 
        [
            button [ OnClick (fun _ -> dispatch Toggle) ] [ str (if model.Visible then "Hide" else "Show") ]
            div [ Display (if model.Visible then "block" else "none") ] [ str "content" ]
        ]
```

Or, pulling `toggleButton` out into its own function so I can show how it would work:

```
let toggleButton dispatch text content =
    div [] 
        [
            button [ OnClick (fun _ -> dispatch Toggle) ] [ str text ]
            div [ Display (if model.Visible then "block" else "none") ] [ str content ]
        ]

let view model dispatch =
    div []
        [
            str "Other elements might go here"
            toggleButton dispatch (if model.Visible then "Hide" else "Show") "content"
        ]
```

Notice how I needed to pass the `dispatch` function through as a parameter to `toggleButton`, so that `toggleButton` will be able to construct the proper behavior for its `OnClick`.

Putting all of this together would look like this:

```
open ALotOfModules

type Model = { Visible: bool;
               DataNotAppearingInThisFilm: int }

type Msg =
    | Show
    | Hide
    | Toggle

let update msg model =
    match msg with
    | Show -> { model with Visible = true }
    | Hide -> { model with Visible = false }
    | Toggle -> { model with Visible = not model.Visible }

let toggleButton dispatch text content =
    div [] 
        [
            button [ OnClick (fun _ -> dispatch Toggle) ] [ str text ]
            div [ Display (if model.Visible then "block" else "none") ] [ str content ]
        ]

let view model dispatch =
    div []
        [
            str "Other elements might go here"
            toggleButton dispatch (if model.Visible then "Hide" else "Show") "content"
        ]
```

Comment: Placeholder in the comment box says to avoid writing here "thanks for the awesome answer", but you get the point.

Comment: Well, actually I am sorta familiar with Elmish as I even use it in my app (without my deep understanding of it, yep). I was just lazy to introduce new models and messages for such a simple thing and wanted to see community's opinion. Well, now I get that mixing architectures is probably the worst thing I can do whereas implementing stuff properly is not such a PITA. So yes, awesome answer, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

My best attempt is to dumbly translate the JavaScript from the link in the question:

```fs
module Markup

open System
open Fable.Helpers.React
open Fable.Helpers.React.Props
open Fable.Import

let toggleButton text content =
    let id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()

    let toggle _ = 
        let contentElement = Browser.document.getElementById id
        let display = if contentElement.style.display = "none" then "block" else "none"
        contentElement.style.display <- display

    div [] 
        [
            button [ OnClick toggle ] [ str text ]
            div [ Id id ] [ str content ]
        ]
```

To be used like `Markup.toggleButton "title" "a lot of content"`